# Pinning trouble with tokio Stream

Tags: rust, stream, rust-tokio

I would like to process incoming websocket messages differently for before 2s has elapsed and after 2s has elapsed.

It's tricky because we only have one `read` (which obviously can't be cloned) and isn't happy about being passed to functions either.

I thought I would `select!` on processing messages and the timer, and then `select!` again for phase 2 after the timer fuses the first `select!`, passing a mutable borrow of `read` to a different processing function.

Turns out I am unable to pass the `read` to a function at all due to pinning.

```rust
use std::time::Duration;

use futures_util::{Stream, StreamExt};
use tokio_tungstenite::connect_async; 

async fn wait_2_seconds() {
    tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(2)).await;
}

async fn process_messages(read: &mut impl Stream) {
    while let Some(m) = read.next().await {
        let data = m.unwrap().into_data();
        println!("{m:?}");
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let url = url::Url::parse("wss://127.0.0.1:12345").unwrap();

    let (ws_stream, _) = connect_async(url).await.expect("Failed to connect");

    // don't plan on sending anything to ws server so discard write half
    let (_, read) = ws_stream.split();

    tokio::select!{
        _ = process_messages(&mut read) => {}, 
        _ = wait_2_seconds() => {}, 
    };
    
    println!("phase 1 complete");
}
```

So I am unsure how to pass (a mut borrow of) `read` to a function.

The error message says consider using `Box::pin` but then I realise I even know *how* to use `Box::pin` in this situation. I tried changing the `process_messages` parameter type to `Box<Pin<&mut impl Stream>>` and realised I needed help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pin the `read` in `main()`. You can either `Box::pin()` it or better, `tokio::pin!()` it (or `futures::pin_mut()`, or even the nightly `std::pin::pin!()`). You also need to specify the `Item` type of the stream. Then take `Pin<&mut impl Stream<Item = ...>>` in `process_messages()`:

```rust
use std::pin::Pin;

use tokio_tungstenite::tungstenite::error::Error;
use tokio_tungstenite::tungstenite::protocol::Message;

async fn process_messages(mut read: Pin<&mut impl Stream<Item = Result<Message, Error>>>) {
    while let Some(m) = read.next().await {
        let data = m.unwrap().into_data();
        println!("{data:?}");
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let url = url::Url::parse("wss://127.0.0.1:12345").unwrap();

    let (ws_stream, _) = connect_async(url).await.expect("Failed to connect");

    // don't plan on sending anything to ws server so discard write half
    let (_, read) = ws_stream.split();
    // Or `let read = Box::pin(read);`.
    tokio::pin!(read);

    tokio::select! {
        _ = process_messages(read.as_mut()) => {},
        _ = wait_2_seconds() => {},
    };

    println!("phase 1 complete");

    // Process after 2 seconds.
    process_messages(read).await;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> The error message says consider using `Box::pin` but then I realise I even know how to use `Box::pin` in this situation. I tried changing the `process_messages` parameter type to `Box<Pin<&mut impl Stream>>` and realised I needed help.

You are almost there. `Box::pin` returns `Pin<Box<_>>`, not `Box<Pin<_>>`. A few more tiny tweaks and `Box::pin` compiles:

```rust
/*
[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "*", features = ["full"] }
tokio-tungstenite = "*"
tungstenite = "*"
futures-util = "*"
url = "*"
*/
use std::time::Duration;
use std::pin::Pin;

use futures_util::{Stream, StreamExt};
use tokio_tungstenite::connect_async;

use tungstenite::protocol::Message;
use tungstenite::error::Error;

async fn wait_2_seconds() {
    tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(2)).await;
}

async fn process_messages(mut read: Pin<Box<impl Stream<Item=Result<Message, Error>>>>) {
    while let Some(m) = read.next().await {
        let data = m.unwrap().into_data();
        println!("{data:?}");
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let url = url::Url::parse("wss://127.0.0.1:12345").unwrap();

    let (ws_stream, _) = connect_async(url).await.expect("Failed to connect");

    // don't plan on sending anything to ws server so discard write half
    let (_, read) = ws_stream.split();

    tokio::select!{
        _ = process_messages(Box::pin(read)) => {}, 
        _ = wait_2_seconds() => {}, 
    };
    
    println!("phase 1 complete");
}
```

[Rustexplorer](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#%2F*%0A%5Bdependencies%5D%0Atokio%20%3D%20%7B%20version%20%3D%20%22*%22%2C%20features%20%3D%20%5B%22full%22%5D%20%7D%0Atokio-tungstenite%20%3D%20%22*%22%0Atungstenite%20%3D%20%22*%22%0Afutures-util%20%3D%20%22*%22%0Aurl%20%3D%20%22*%22%0A*%2F%0Ause%20std%3A%3Atime%3A%3ADuration%3B%0Ause%20std%3A%3Apin%3A%3APin%3B%0A%0Ause%20futures_util%3A%3A%7BStream%2C%20StreamExt%7D%3B%0Ause%20tokio_tungstenite%3A%3Aconnect_async%3B%0A%0Ause%20tungstenite%3A%3Aprotocol%3A%3AMessage%3B%0Ause%20tungstenite%3A%3Aerror%3A%3AError%3B%0A%0Aasync%20fn%20wait_2_seconds()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20tokio%3A%3Atime%3A%3Asleep(Duration%3A%3Afrom_secs(2)).await%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aasync%20fn%20process_messages(mut%20read%3A%20Pin%3CBox%3Cimpl%20Stream%3CItem%3DResult%3CMessage%2C%20Error%3E%3E%3E%3E)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20while%20let%20Some(m)%20%3D%20read.next().await%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20data%20%3D%20m.unwrap().into_data()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7Bdata%3A%3F%7D%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%23%5Btokio%3A%3Amain%5D%0Aasync%20fn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20url%20%3D%20url%3A%3AUrl%3A%3Aparse(%22wss%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A12345%22).unwrap()%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20(ws_stream%2C%20_)%20%3D%20connect_async(url).await.expect(%22Failed%20to%20connect%22)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20don%27t%20plan%20on%20sending%20anything%20to%20ws%20server%20so%20discard%20write%20half%0A%20%20%20%20let%20(_%2C%20read)%20%3D%20ws_stream.split()%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20tokio%3A%3Aselect!%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20_%20%3D%20process_messages(Box%3A%3Apin(read))%20%3D%3E%20%7B%7D%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20_%20%3D%20wait_2_seconds()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%7D%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22phase%201%20complete%22)%3B%0A%7D) (compiles, but panics at runtime because you can't bind to the socket).